# Как прочитать числа из файла

Tags: java, файловый-ввод-вывод

У меня есть файл с следующими числами:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
> 27 28 29 30 31 32  33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
> 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72
> 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95
> 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105

И я хочу их вывести на консоль.

Я написала код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
      File f=new File("C:\\Users\\Tatiana\\Documents\\e.txt");

      FileReader is =new FileReader(f);

      System.out.println(is);
      is.close();

}
```

Вот что мне выводит на консоль:

> java.io.FileReader@10f87f48

Comment: https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/filewriter-i-filereader/

Comment: Откройте любой учебник по Java и/или статью в интернете по файловому вводу-выводу... Вы создаёте объект `FileReader`, а потом пытаетесь вывести **объект** на консоль. Вот и получаете его полное имя и адрес в памяти. Вспомните (или узнайте) про метод `read()` этого класса и используйте его. Так же советую не писать `throws IOException`, а и использовать `try/catch` и закрывать файл в блоке `finally` или пользоваться `try` с ресурсами. В данный момент при возникновении исключения файл может остаться открытым, а утечка памяти - это плохо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Вот так если все твои числа записаны просто через пробел, и тебе нужно вывести их так же как они записаны:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File f=new File("D:\\путь к файлу\\e.txt");

        FileReader is =new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("").append(br.readLine());
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Вот так если нужно вывести каждое значение отдельно (при этом не разбирая его)

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File f=new File("D:\\Путь к файлу\\e.txt");

        FileReader is =new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("").append(br.readLine());
        String[] tmp = sb.toString().split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
            System.out.println(tmp[i]);
        is.close();

    }
}
```

Ну а вообще, установи какую-нить хорошую IDE, которая подсказывает что можно в конкретном контексте, а чего нельзя, и изучай язык, библиотеку функций, и IDE вместе и с большим количеством практики.

P.S.: и Стас в комментарии тоже очень полезный совет дает

Answer (score 1):

То, что Вы видите, это результат стандартной реализации метода `toString()`. Чаще всего, это значение не несет осмысленного значения, и для представления объекта в виде текста, метод надо перегружать.

В Вашем примере Вы пытаетесь представить объект класса `FileReader` в виде текста, что вызывает как раз стандартную реализацию `toString()`

Я бы предложил Вам упростить код используя стандартные средства Java для разбиения входящего потока на токены. Например Ваша задача решится вот так:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("PATH_TO_FILE_HERE"));
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
    }
}
```